# Want to select only directory path from file dialog

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement this function where I want to get a path from selecting folder from file dialog. I can only find examples on how to select only files, but not just folders. Do you know where I can find some examples on that?

Comment: Browser file dialogs are for picking files.

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh! What is it called then? :))

Comment: For security reasons, Javascript is not allowed to access the local filesystem. You cannot see, read, write or execute files on a user's PC. You can only read one file that the user has explicitly granted access to via an `<input type="file">` element, so accessing a directory path is pointless. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's not called anything; all the browser file dialog can do is identify a single file.

Comment: @Robb216 I bit hard to explain, but I can try. I will need to put a path for images to save. This happens in "settings" mode.